# YouTube .Net API - Not getting correct View Counts

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube.net-api

I've managed to plug away through the YouTube documentation, and have managed to successfully implement the majority of what I want to work.  My question is, I get the video View count and it comes back lower than the actual video on YouTube.  It was fine this morning and both showed correctly, but now my version is out by 4 views.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Or can tell me if they update the values every 5/10/15/24 hours?

Comment: Yeah, it is almost definitely cached.  Probably on the order of every couple of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest reading:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=174b1eaf86454a61&hl=en&fid=174b1eaf86454a6100046e4bb7fc80f8

Sadly it appears that viewcounts are often wrong, inaccurate, not increasing correctly, or sometimes just plain stuck.

Some more interesting points on the developer forums:

http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/ba0924df15b53b42?pli=1

I hope your project doesn't rely on totally accurate counts, but it looks like - for now anyway, it seems like they can't be trusted reliably.